# number of sub rectangles

Tags: java, arrays

I have an m*n 2D array in java such that some elements of this array are equal to one and some are equal to zero. I want to find the number of sub rectangles of this 2D array with area k consisting only of zeros. What should I do?

for example for the following array, the number of sub rectangles of this 2D array with area 2 consisting only of zeros is 11.

1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0

0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1

0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0

My idea was to count all the sub rectangles with area k and then omit the ones which consist 1 but I found it difficult.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: @user7 My idea was to count all the sub rectangles with area k and then omit the ones which consist 1 but I found it difficult.

Answer (score 1):

`countSubRectangles` counts `height` x `width` rectangles.

```
static boolean areAllZeros(int[][] matrix, int top, int left, int height, int width) {
    int maxHeight = matrix.length;
    int maxWidth = matrix[0].length;
    int bottom = top + height;
    int right = left + width;
    if (bottom > maxHeight || right > maxWidth)
        return false;
    for (int i = top; i < bottom; ++i)
        for (int j = left; j < right; ++j)
            if (matrix[i][j] != 0)
                return false;
    return true;
}

static int countSubRectangles(int[][] matrix, int height, int width) {
    int maxHeight = matrix.length;
    int maxWidth = matrix[0].length;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxHeight; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < maxWidth; ++j)
            if (areAllZeros(matrix, i, j, height, width))
                ++count;
    return count;
}
```

and

```
int[][] matrix = {
    {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1},
    {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
};
System.out.println(
    countSubRectangles(matrix, 1, 2)      // count 1x2 sub rectangles
    + countSubRectangles(matrix, 2, 1));  // count 2x1 sub rectangles
// -> 11
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to count every sub rectangle with **area >= k**. 1 is allowed in sub rectangle according to your description. My suggestion is this:

```
for(int height=1; height<m; height++)
    for(int width=1; width<n && width>=k/height; width++)
        for(int y=0; y+height<=m; y++)
            for(int x=0; x+width<=n; x++){
                // check if the sub rectangle (x, y)-(x+width-1, y+height-1) contains k zeros
            }
```