# How to find all sub rectangles using fastest algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

An example , suppose we have a 2D array such as:

```
A= [
    [1,0,0],
    [1,0,0],
    [0,1,1]
   ]
```

The task is to find all sub rectangles **concluding only zeros**. So the output of this algorithm should be:

```
[[0,1,0,2] , [0,1,1,1] , [0,2,1,2] , [0,1,1,2] ,[1,1,1,2], [2,0,2,0] , 
[0,1,0,1] , [0,2,0,2] , [1,1,1,1] , [1,2,1,2]]
```

Where i,j in `[ i , j , a , b ]` are coordinates of rectangle's starting point and a,b are coordinates of rectangle's ending point.

I found some algorithms for example [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62465110/number-of-sub-rectangles) and [Link2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-rectangles-filled-0/) but I think first one is simplest algorithm and we want fastest.For the second one we see that the algorithm only calculates rectangles and not **all sub rectangles**.

Question:
Does anyone know better or fastest algorithm for this problem? My idea is to use dynamic programming but how to use isn't easy for me.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the fastest algorithm must be based on dynamic programming.  That's not necessarily true.

Comment: I see ten rectangles.

Comment: For a rectangle of size m.n, there are up to m.(m+1).n.(n+1)/4 subrectangles.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes there are 10,edited thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume an initial array of size c columns x r rows.

Every 0 is a rectangle of size 1x1.

Now perform an "horizontal dilation", i.e. replace every element by the maximum of itself and the one to its right, and drop the last element in the row. E.g.

```
1 0 0    1 0
1 0 0 -> 1 0
0 1 1    1 1
```

Every zero now corresponds to a 1x2 rectangle in the original array. You can repeat this c-1 times, until there is a single column left.

```
1 0 0    1 0    1
1 0 0 -> 1 0 -> 1
0 1 1    1 1    1
```

The zeroes correspond to a 1xc rectangles in the original array (initially c columns).

For every dilated array, perform a similar "vertical dilation".

```
1 0 0    1 0    1
1 0 0 -> 1 0 -> 1
0 1 1    1 1    1
  |       |     |
  V       V     V
1 0 0    1 0    1
1 1 1 -> 1 1 -> 1
  |       |     |
  V       V     V
1 1 1 -> 1 1 -> 1
```

In these rxc arrays, the zeroes correspond to the subrectangles of all possible sizes. (Here, 5 of size 1x1, 2 of size 2x1, 2 of size 1x2 and one of size 2x2.)

The total workload to detect the zeroes and compute the dilations is of order O(c²r²). I guess that this is worst-case optimal. (In case an array contains no zeroes, there is no need to continue any dilation.)

Comment: Thanks for the algorithm. That seem to be nice. But I have some problems understanding it. How you conclude that we have 5 of size 1*1 rectangles using this algorithm? can you do more examples in your answer like you said for 1*2 ?

Comment: @program_craft: count all zeroes in the nine arrays. This is immediate.

Comment: It's interesting. What's mathematical explanation behind this? Do you know any related article or website?

Comment: @program_craft: this is no rocket science. A dilation just shrinks a zero-rectangle by one column/row.

Comment: I know from your algorithm how to count all the rectangles and this was a new and great answer.But im curious to go in deep. In which step(array)you found that there is 1 of 2*2 rectangle?

Comment: @program_craft: come on, I listed them in reading order. I guess that you are still missing the dilation principle. I suggest that you work out examples by hand.